# Plotting $B_1(0)$ in ($\mathbb R^2$, $||.||_1$)

Tags: normed-spaces, orthonormal

> Plot $B_1(0)$ in ($\mathbb R^2$, $||.||_1$)

So I should draw a circle of center the origin O($0,0$) and radius $r=1$ in an orthonormal system ($O,i,j$)?

If yes can someone please show me a picture of the plotting just to make sure I drew it correctly? Thank you

Comment: Do you understand the definitions here? Do you understand the difference between "$B_1(0)$ in $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$" and "$B_1(0)$ in $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_1)$"?

Comment: No, what's the difference

Comment: you should check your notes to confirm this, but typically
$$
B_1(0) = \{x \in \Bbb R^n : \|x\| = 1\},
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the norm from the parentheses. So, we end up with a different set in the second case.

Comment: And so how would a plot the ball, I still did not understand..

Comment: And so how do I plot the ball. I still don't understand..